# Solspace Calendar - How do I show current date of repeating events?

Tags: solspace-calendar

I have a page that shows the Day's events. It currently uses:

```
{event_first_date}
```

This is great except with repeating events - which continues to show the first date of the event. I reviewed the documentation but did not see an option to display

```
{event_current_date}
```

or something like that. Any clues as to what that would be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete answer to your question requires a bit more context than you have provided, but this is a common question, so I will make some assumptions. :)

If this is a page using Calendar:Events tag to display complete/more info about an event, and you are linking to this page from a page such as a full month view calendar, we'll often use this workaround:

In the full month view template (using Calendar:Cal), we'll adjust the link for the title of the event to have this extra code:

```
{if event_recurs}{event_start_date format="%Y/%m/%d"}/{/if}
```

So, the complete code for the title link would be:

```
<a href="{path='calendar/events'}/{event_url_title}/{if event_recurs}{event_start_date format="%Y/%m/%d"}/{/if}">{event_title}</a>
```

What that will do is add some fake date values into the URI, which can be retrieved later ;)

Then, in your Event detail page (using Calendar:Events tag), you would have something like this code:

```
{exp:calendar:events
   event_name="{segment_3}" <!-- grabs URL title from 3rd segment, where we sent it -->
   event_limit="1"
   dynamic="no"
}
   <h2>{event_title}</h3>
   <p>
      {if event_recurs}
         {exp:calendar:date
            base_date="{segment_4}-{segment_5}-{segment_6}"
            output_date="today"
         }
            {date format="%l, %F %j"} @ {event_start_date format="%g:%i%a"}
         {/exp:calendar:date}
      {if:else}
         {event_start_date format="%l, %F %j @ %g:%i%a"}
      {/if}
   </p>
{/exp:calendar:events}
```

You'll see that we're using the date values from the URI that we passed on from the previous template, and now feeding them into the Calendar:Date tag, and telling it to parse those segments into a formatted date. We then use the {event_start_date ... } variable, but only for the time parsing.